# How to send parameter to this java class?

Tags: java

i am completely new on java, and i am trying to implement a print test using Zebra SDK.
this Zebra SDK (at the end of the class there is a "getConfigLabel"), prints a constant "TEST", so i want to send a variable insted of constant. to get this, i understand that i have to send a parameter to the class, but it is not clear for me how to get this done.
thanks.

here is the class:

```
/***********************************************
 * CONFIDENTIAL AND PROPRIETARY 
 * 
 * The source code and other information contained herein is the confidential and the exclusive property of
 * ZIH Corp. and is subject to the terms and conditions in your end user license agreement.
 * This source code, and any other information contained herein, shall not be copied, reproduced, published, 
 * displayed or distributed, in whole or in part, in any medium, by any means, for any purpose except as
 * expressly permitted under such license agreement.
 * 
 * Copyright ZIH Corp. 2012
 * 
 * ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
 ***********************************************/

package com.zebra.android.devdemo.connectivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.zebra.android.devdemo.R;
import com.zebra.sdk.comm.BluetoothConnection;
import com.zebra.sdk.comm.Connection;
import com.zebra.sdk.comm.ConnectionException;
import com.zebra.sdk.comm.TcpConnection;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.PrinterLanguage;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.ZebraPrinter;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.ZebraPrinterFactory;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.ZebraPrinterLanguageUnknownException;

public class ConnectivityDemo extends Activity {

    private Connection printerConnection;
    private RadioButton btRadioButton;
    private ZebraPrinter printer;
    private TextView statusField;
    private EditText macAddress, ipDNSAddress, portNumber, vtextToPrint;
    private Button testButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.connection_screen_with_status);

        ipDNSAddress = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.ipAddressInput);
        ipDNSAddress.setText(SettingsHelper.getIp(this));

        vtextToPrint = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.textToPrint);


        portNumber = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.portInput);
        portNumber.setText(SettingsHelper.getPort(this));

        macAddress = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.macInput);
        macAddress.setText(SettingsHelper.getBluetoothAddress(this));

        statusField = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.statusText);
        btRadioButton = (RadioButton) this.findViewById(R.id.bluetoothRadio);

        testButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        testButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        enableTestButton(false);
                        Looper.prepare();
                        doConnectionTest();
                        Looper.loop();
                        Looper.myLooper().quit();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });

        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (checkedId == R.id.bluetoothRadio) {
                    toggleEditField(macAddress, true);
                    toggleEditField(portNumber, false);
                    toggleEditField(ipDNSAddress, false);
                } else {
                    toggleEditField(portNumber, true);
                    toggleEditField(ipDNSAddress, true);
                    toggleEditField(macAddress, false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void toggleEditField(EditText editText, boolean set) {
        /*
         * Note: Disabled EditText fields may still get focus by some other means, and allow text input.
         *       See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2771
         */
        editText.setEnabled(set);
        editText.setFocusable(set);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(set);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (printerConnection != null && printerConnection.isConnected()) {
            disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void enableTestButton(final boolean enabled) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                testButton.setEnabled(enabled);
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isBluetoothSelected() {
        return btRadioButton.isChecked();
    }

    public ZebraPrinter connect() {
        setStatus("Connecting...", Color.YELLOW);
        printerConnection = null;
        if (isBluetoothSelected()) {
            printerConnection = new BluetoothConnection(getMacAddressFieldText());
            SettingsHelper.saveBluetoothAddress(this, getMacAddressFieldText());
        } else {
            try {
                int port = Integer.parseInt(getTcpPortNumber());
                printerConnection = new TcpConnection(getTcpAddress(), port);
                SettingsHelper.saveIp(this, getTcpAddress());
                SettingsHelper.savePort(this, getTcpPortNumber());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                setStatus("Port Number Is Invalid", Color.RED);
                return null;
            }
        }

        try {
            printerConnection.open();
            setStatus("Connected", Color.GREEN);
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            setStatus("Comm Error! Disconnecting", Color.RED);
            DemoSleeper.sleep(1000);
            disconnect();
        }

        ZebraPrinter printer = null;

        if (printerConnection.isConnected()) {
            try {
                printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(printerConnection);
                setStatus("Determining Printer Language", Color.YELLOW);
                PrinterLanguage pl = printer.getPrinterControlLanguage();
                setStatus("Printer Language " + pl, Color.BLUE);
            } catch (ConnectionException e) {
                setStatus("Unknown Printer Language", Color.RED);
                printer = null;
                DemoSleeper.sleep(1000);
                disconnect();
            } catch (ZebraPrinterLanguageUnknownException e) {
                setStatus("Unknown Printer Language", Color.RED);
                printer = null;
                DemoSleeper.sleep(1000);
                disconnect();
            }
        }

        return printer;
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            setStatus("Disconnecting", Color.RED);
            if (printerConnection != null) {
                printerConnection.close();
            }
            setStatus("Not Connected", Color.RED);
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            setStatus("COMM Error! Disconnected", Color.RED);
        } finally {
            enableTestButton(true);
        }
    }

    private void setStatus(final String statusMessage, final int color) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                statusField.setBackgroundColor(color);
                statusField.setText(statusMessage);
            }
        });
        DemoSleeper.sleep(200);
    }

    private String getMacAddressFieldText() {
        return macAddress.getText().toString();
    }

    private String getTcpAddress() {
        return ipDNSAddress.getText().toString();
    }

    private String getTcpPortNumber() {
        return portNumber.getText().toString();
    }

    private void doConnectionTest() {
        printer = connect();
        if (printer != null) {
            sendTestLabel();
        } else {
            disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void sendTestLabel() {
        try {
            byte[] configLabel = getConfigLabel();
            printerConnection.write(configLabel);
            setStatus("Sending Data", Color.BLUE);
            DemoSleeper.sleep(500);
            if (printerConnection instanceof BluetoothConnection) {
                String friendlyName = ((BluetoothConnection) printerConnection).getFriendlyName();
                setStatus(friendlyName, Color.MAGENTA);
                DemoSleeper.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            setStatus(e.getMessage(), Color.RED);
        } finally {
            disconnect();
        }
    }

    /*
    * Returns the command for a test label depending on the printer control language
    * The test label is a box with the word "TEST" inside of it
    * 
    * _________________________
    * |                       |
    * |                       |
    * |        TEST           |
    * |                       |
    * |                       |
    * |_______________________|
    * 
    * 
    */
    private byte[] getConfigLabel() {
        PrinterLanguage printerLanguage = printer.getPrinterControlLanguage();

        byte[] configLabel = null;
        if (printerLanguage == PrinterLanguage.ZPL) {
            configLabel = "^XA^FO17,16^GB379,371,8^FS^FT65,255^A0N,135,134^FDTEST^FS^XZ".getBytes();
        } else if (printerLanguage == PrinterLanguage.CPCL) {
            String cpclConfigLabel = "! 0 200 200 406 1\r\n" + "ON-FEED IGNORE\r\n" + "BOX 20 20 380 380 8\r\n" + "T 0 6 137 177 TEST\r\n" + "PRINT\r\n";
            configLabel = cpclConfigLabel.getBytes();
        }
        return configLabel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Good God Almighty, that's a lot of code.  Could you pare it down a bit so that the code snippet you refer to in your question is present in the code block instead?

Comment: ...Oh.  And, uh, if the copyright notice is legit, you *might* be in some hot water behind posting it.

Comment: I would delete this post ASAP.

Comment: Hey, no please, wait a momment, as i said before, i am new on java. and i am using this code to understand better the funcionality, so i can develop my own. in fact, i left the copyrigth intentionally.

Comment: Sure, but two things are wrong:  it's code that I doubt that we mere mortals were meant to see, and if you *had* removed the copyright, that would have made matters more painful.  I *did* find [a Github repo](https://github.com/walvarado/Emt/blob/master/Emt/src/com/zebra/android/devdemo/connectivity/ConnectivityDemo.java) with pretty much the same thing in it, so I'm not entirely sure if this is code that ZIH released or not (it doesn't seem like it is).  For a beginner, this is **way** too much code to take in; I'd recommend something smaller.

Comment: ok, just to be clear, the code shown here, can be downloaded from Zebra web page, in fact, here is the video where they show how to get it done, step by step: http://www.zebra.com/isv/video/GettingStartedWithAndroid/Getting%20Started%20WIth%20Android%20Dev.mp4.

Comment: ok, all i ask is a way to print something different than TEST, i will like to see it working with a parameter to print something else. i can't not reduce the code, because i don't really now about java and i  surely will broke it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private byte[] getConfigLabel(String parameter) {

     .....
     String cpclConfigLabel = "! 0 200 200 406 1\r\n" + "ON-FEED IGNORE\r\n" + "BOX 20 20 380 380 8\r\n" + "T 0 6 137 177 " + parameter + "r\n" + "PRINT\r\n";
     .......
}
```

This is how you take in an argument into a method.

When calling the method getConfigLabel, make sure you pass in the parameter String, if not it will causes error.

```
byte[] configLabel = getConfigLabel("Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

At this line, which is 9 from the end:

```
configLabel = "^XA^FO17,16^GB379,371,8^FS^FT65,255^A0N,135,134^FDTEST^FS^XZ".getBytes();
```

you can replace TEST with your variable, e.g:

```
configLabel = "^XA^FO17,16^GB379,371,8^FS^FT65,255^A0N,135,134^FD" + text + "^FS^XZ".getBytes();
```

You also need to declare this variable somewhere in the `getConfigLabel` method or pass it to it.

I suggest changing method signature to `getConfigLabel(String text)` and modify line 9 from th end. In that case in methond `sendTestLabel` you can replace

```
byte[] configLabel = getConfigLabel();
```

with

```
String text = "some text...";
byte[] configLabel = getConfigLabel(text);
```

*BTW, this is only the way to print something instead of "TEST". I suggest you use this only for understanding of how it works. If you want to further customize this code, you may need to add another methods, for fine printing*